# ord() Function or ASCII Character Code of String with Z3 Solver

Tags: python-3.4, z3, z3py

How can I convert a `z3.String` to a sequence of ASCII values?

For example, here is some code that I thought would check whether the ASCII values of all the characters in the string add up to 100:

```
import z3

def add_ascii_values(password):
    return sum(ord(character) for character in password)

password = z3.String("password")
solver = z3.Solver()
ascii_sum = add_ascii_values(password)
solver.add(ascii_sum == 100)

print(solver.check())
print(solver.model())
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but SeqRef found
```

It's apparent that `ord` doesn't work with `z3.String`. Is there something in Z3 that does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 2022 Update

Below answer, written back in 2018, no longer applies; as strings in SMTLib received a major update and thus the code given is outdated. Keeping it here for archival purposes, and in case you happen to have a really old z3 that you cannot upgrade for some reason. See the other answer for a variant that works with the new unicode strings in SMTLib: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689580/936310

## Old Answer from 2018

You're conflating Python strings and Z3 Strings; and unfortunately the two are quite different types.

In Z3py, a `String` is simply a sequence of 8-bit values. And what you can do with a Z3 is actually quite limited; for instance you cannot iterate over the characters like you did in your `add_ascii_values` function. See this page for what the allowed functions are: https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/sequences (This page lists the functions in SMTLib parlance; but the equivalent ones are available from the z3py interface.)

There are a few important restrictions/things that you need to keep in mind when working with Z3 sequences and strings:

- You have to be very explicit about the lengths; In particular, you cannot `sum` over strings of arbitrary symbolic length. There are a few things you can do without specifying the length explicitly, but these are limited. (Like regex matches, substring extraction etc.)
- You cannot extract a character out of a string. This is an oversight in my opinion, but SMTLib just has no way of doing so for the time being. Instead, you get a list of length 1. This causes a lot of headaches in programming, but there are workarounds. See below.
- Anytime you loop over a string/sequence, you have to go up to a fixed bound. There are ways to program so you can cover "all strings upto length N" for some constant "N", but they do get hairy.

Keeping all this in mind, I'd go about coding your example like the following; restricting `password` to be precisely 10 characters long:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

# Work around the fact that z3 has no way of giving us an element at an index. Sigh.
ordHelperCounter = 0
def OrdAt(inp, i):
    global ordHelperCounter
    v = BitVec("OrdAtHelper_%d_%d" % (i, ordHelperCounter), 8)
    ordHelperCounter += 1
    s.add(Unit(v) == SubString(inp, i, 1))
    return v

# Your original function, but note the addition of len parameter and use of Sum
def add_ascii_values(password, len):
    return Sum([OrdAt(password, i) for i in range(len)])

# We'll have to force a constant length
length = 10
password = String("password")
s.add(Length(password) == 10)
ascii_sum = add_ascii_values(password, length)
s.add(ascii_sum == 100)

# Also require characters to be printable so we can view them:
for i in range(length):
  v = OrdAt(password, i)
  s.add(v >= 0x20)
  s.add(v <= 0x7E)

print(s.check())
print(s.model()[password])
```

The `OrdAt` function works around the problem of not being able to extract characters. Also note how we use `Sum` instead of `sum`, and how all "loops" are of fixed iteration count. I also added constraints to make all the ascii codes printable for convenience.

When you run this, you get:

```
sat
":X|@`y}@@@"
```

Let's check it's indeed good:

```
>>> len(":X|@`y}@@@")
10
>>> sum(ord(character) for character in ":X|@`y}@@@")
868
```

So, we did get a length 10 string; but how come the ord's don't sum up to 100? Now, you have to remember sequences are composed of 8-bit values, and thus the arithmetic is done modulo 256. So, the sum actually is:

```
>>> sum(ord(character) for character in ":X|@`y}@@@") % 256
100
```

To avoid the overflows, you can either use larger bit-vectors, or more simply use Z3's unbounded Integer type `Int`. To do so, use the `BV2Int` function, by simply changing `add_ascii_values` to:

```
def add_ascii_values(password, len):
    return Sum([BV2Int(OrdAt(password, i)) for i in range(len)])
```

Now we'd get:

```
unsat
```

That's because each of our characters has at least value `0x20` and we wanted 10 characters; so there's no way to make them all sum up to 100. And z3 is precisely telling us that. If you increase your sum goal to something more reasonable, you'd start getting proper values.

Programming with z3py is different than regular programming with Python, and z3 `String` objects are quite different than those of Python itself. Note that the sequence/string logic isn't even standardized yet by the SMTLib folks, so things can change. (In particular, I'm hoping they'll add functionality for extracting elements at an index!).

Having said all this, going over the https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/sequences would be a good start to get familiar with them, and feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Rather than limiting myself to 8-bit `BitVec`s, I found that I could use longer `BitVec`s and then do `s.add(Unit(Extract(7, 0, v)) == SubString(inp, i, 1))` instead of `s.add(Unit(v) == SubString(inp, i, 1))`. This allowed me to get around the integer overflows.

Comment: I took all this and made this gist: https://gist.github.com/wecsam/0345ed7eab3911a5bdea27673d38baf9

Comment: Good work! A simpler way to avoid overflows would be to just use the `BV2Int` function, which converts a bit-vector value to an unbounded integer. I think that would work better for this problem, avoiding zero-extension/extraction etc. I updated my answer to include that as an option.

Comment: Also, this line https://gist.github.com/wecsam/0345ed7eab3911a5bdea27673d38baf9#file-password_sum_and_product-py-L116 is better coded as `solver.check() == z3.sat`

Comment: Thanks! I took your second suggestion and change that one line. As for using `BV2Int`, in my exact case, I actually intended for the sum to overflow after 32 bits anyway; this was for a reverse engineering challenge. Nonetheless, thanks for adding that function to your answer; it'll probably help someone in the future.

Comment: Helpful answer, thanks. It's been some time since the question and the rise4fun website seems to be down today. Do you have any other resources to learn more about manipulating strings with z3?

Comment: @Elf Well, reviewing this answer a few things did happen in the mean time. First, strings are now formalized by SMTLib: https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-UnicodeStrings.shtml In particular, they support unicode; so strings are no longer just a sequence of 8-bit bit-vectors. (So some of the contents of this answer is rather outdated.) Unfortunately they did not add an element extraction function, which I find rather problematic. As far as resources go, I'm not aware of anything new written on the topic, unfortunately. Your best bet is to try it out and ask questions in this forum as needed.

Comment: @Elf You're correct that rise4fun site is dead indeed, though I heard Microsoft is planning a revival of it, moving it to a more modern platform. However, this work hasn't even started yet. I expect it'll be up and running towards the end of 2022; assuming they have someone working on it by this summer.

Comment: After trying the answer, it indeed is outdated, unfortunately. It doesn't work anymore and a Z3Exception "sort mismatch" is raised in `OrdAt` in the line that adds a condition to the solver.

Comment: @Elf yes, that is expected. Since strings are no longer sequences of bit-vectors, this answer no longer is valid. Feel free to modernize it and post an updated version!

Comment: I would love to do so but I'm new to z3 and actually not capable of finding an alternative right now unfortunately. I needed to do this kind of things for a project, and I ended up dealing with char codes instead, but it's way too messy.

Comment: @Elf The required changes are actually pretty simple. However, it seems the Python API is missing some of the functions needed for this purpose. (I reported this here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/5773) Once the API is updated, I'll update this answer accordingly.

Comment: @Elf I added a new answer showing how to code it using the new string idioms. Note that to be able to run the code, you literally need a version of z3 that's built from sources as of today (Jan 12 2022) or later, as it contains functions that were just added to the code base. Looks like the solution is actually a lot cleaner now with the new functions directly available in the API. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer dates back to 2018, and things have changed in the mean time which makes the proposed solution no longer work with z3. In particular:

- Strings are now formalized by SMTLib. (See https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-UnicodeStrings.shtml)
- Unlike the previous version (where strings were simply sequences of bit vectors), strings are now sequences unicode characters. So, the coding used in the previous answer no longer applies.

Based on this, the following would be how this problem would be coded, assuming a password of length 3:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

# Ord of character at position i
def OrdAt(inp, i):
    return StrToCode(SubString(inp, i, 1))

# Adding ascii values for a string of a given length
def add_ascii_values(password, len):
    return Sum([OrdAt(password, i) for i in range(len)])

# We'll have to force a constant length
length = 3
password = String("password")
s.add(Length(password) == length)
ascii_sum = add_ascii_values(password, length)
s.add(ascii_sum == 100)

# Also require characters to be printable so we can view them:
for i in range(length):
  v = OrdAt(password, i)
  s.add(v >= 0x20)
  s.add(v <= 0x7E)

print(s.check())
print(s.model()[password])
```

**Note** Due to https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/5773, to be able to run the above, you need a version of z3 that you downloaded on Jan 12, 2022 or afterwards! As of this date, none of the released versions of z3 contain the functions used in this answer.

When run, the above prints:

```
sat
" #!"
```

You can check that it satisfies the given constraint, i.e., the ord of characters add up to 100:

```
>>> sum(ord(c) for c in " #!")
100
```

Note that we no longer have to worry about modular arithmetic, since `OrdAt` returns an actual integer, not a bit-vector.

Comment: Wow, thanks for posting an updated answer.