# I don't understand how I can develop length method in Z3py

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I want to develop a function to calculate the length in Z3 for a list, but I think that I am doing it wrong. I am new using Z3, and I don't have a lot idea. 
I did it:

```
def length(numbers):
    cont = 0
    x, length = Ints('x length')
    s = Solver()

    for x in numbers:
        cont +=1        

    dato = Implies(cont >0 , length == cont), Or(Implies(cont == 0, length == cont))
    s.add(dato)
    n = Solver()
    solve(dato)
    if s.check() == unsat:
        print(cont)
    else:
       # print("true")
        print(s.model())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = [1, 2,"p", 3,6,503]
    length([])
    length(my_list)
```

But I think that I should to use a function of Z3, because if I want to make more methods (isNull,isEmpty...) and call it at the same time that Length for make axioms,but I can't for the now implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve, but looks like you're conflating Python lists with Z3 sequences. Use the former when you have a concrete list, and the latter when the list can be of some arbitrary length itself.

For the latter, you also want to use the sequence logic, which already defines functions `length`, `isNull`, `isEmpty` etc., but with different names. See here for the details: https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/sequences#h22

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but if I want to use a list in Z3 how could I do it? Also, the method length of sequences is interesting but how I can use it in Z3py?

Comment: Stack-overflow works the best when you post a specific question. You can also search for many existing questions. Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774838/ord-function-or-ascii-character-code-of-string-with-z3-solver/53785639#53785639 If not, try formulating and posting a specific problem that we can help with.